# MYSQL INSERT with random values between 1 - 5

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do an INSER INTO statement but i need some fields to generate random numbers each time: Example

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,RAND NUMBER,RAND NUMBER,...);
```

So each time it enters a random number into columns when creating a new record. SO most values will be static but some need to be RAND between a number set for example 1 -5 or 1000 - 5000.

Any help?

Comment: [This link](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/rand.php) shows you how to use `RAND()` to generate a random number within a range.  You can just plug this into your `INSERT` statement.

Comment: I tried that so in the values I have VALUES ('511222', RAND()*(5-1)+1, '323632') Because I want numbers between 1 and 5. using MYSQL work bench not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: @Speedychuck did that not work ?

Answer (score 2):

Using this function should work:

```
FLOOR(min+RAND()*(max-min))

INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,SELECT FLOOR(5+RAND()*(1-5)),SELECT FLOOR(5+RAND()*(1-5)),...);
```

Comment: How would this look in the insert statement? @Zoidburg

Comment: Just tried this: getting a 1582 incorrect parameter count in call to native function floor.

Comment: Need an extra `)` after `(10-100)`

Comment: Ok this worked, however its inserting as 0 I have (1-5) should it not be between 1 and 5 that is generated?

Comment: Ok its because the db only accepts numbers as strings grrr! I need to populate that field with a number between 1 and 5 which is entered as a string how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean something like this
    `CAST(FLOOR(5+RAND()*(1-5)) AS CHAR)`

Comment: This would work, however, just noticed it is set to TINYINT so how do I get around this? Thanks for help by way.

Comment: So the column only accepts TINYINT and the default expression is set to '2' SO how do I get CAST(FLOOR(5+RAND()*(1-5)) AS CHAR) to add as a TINYINT?

Answer (score 1):

Insert some rows with random numbers from 1 to 5 in some columns.

Schema:

```
create table friday1
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    value1 int not null,
    value2 int not null
);
```

Insert 3 rows:

```
insert friday1(value1,value2) select floor(rand()*5)+1,floor(rand()*5)+1;
insert friday1(value1,value2) select floor(rand()*5)+1,floor(rand()*5)+1;
insert friday1(value1,value2) select floor(rand()*5)+1,floor(rand()*5)+1;
```

Stored Proc helper:

```
drop procedure if exists insertMany;
DELIMITER $$
create procedure insertMany
(   howMany int
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE soFar int default 0;

    set howMany=least(howMany,500); -- max out at 500 regardless of IN parameter (RAND is slow)
    WHILE soFar<howMany DO
        insert friday1(value1,value2) select floor(rand()*5)+1,floor(rand()*5)+1;
        set soFar=soFar+1;
    END WHILE;
    select soFar; -- # of times in loop
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Test:

```
call insertMany(200);
```

Results:

```
select count(*) as theCount, 
least(min(value1),min(value2)) as theMin, 
greatest(max(value1),max(value2)) as theMax 
from friday1; 

+----------+--------+--------+
| theCount | theMin | theMax |
+----------+--------+--------+
|      203 |      1 |      5 |
+----------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1473-seeding-sql-rand-method-with-newid-for-per-row-random-values-thanks-joshua-cyr.htm).

You can use RAND(), but as it says in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx),

> If seed is not specified, the SQL Server Database Engine assigns a seed value at random. For a specified seed value, the result returned is always the same.

Hope this helps you

**EDIT:**

So if you want to use it in the INSERT INTO....i assume

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, RAND(CAST( NEWID() AS varbinary )) * 5, RAND(CAST( NEWID() AS varbinary )) * 1000,...)
```

If this doesnt help, thumbs down as I'm going from what I'd try first and im not testing

Comment: Need to know how to use it in an INSERT INTO :( so when I use the insert it will Generate the number between 1 and 5 for that column

Comment: Look at my edit, try it out....youll need to round the number if you want a whole number

Comment: CAST(FLOOR(5+RAND()*(1-5)) AS CHAR) Now works, however when I check what the column accepts it is a TINYINT. So FLOOR RAND generates the  number between 1 and 5 but wont insert it into the column becasue its trying to add an INT which is then converted into a String. How do I add as TINYINT is my issues. @Alex Grogan

Comment: Do you really want to use a TINYINT? It only has a range of 0-255? You're betting off changing the design of the table so its an INT instead